# Formvalidation.io and array input fields with index

Tags: arrays, indexing, formvalidation.io

I am using the Formvalidation.io plugin and this works perfect with

```
<input type="text" name="url[]" required />
```

with the following validation code

```
'url[]': {
    validators: {
        stringLength: {
             min: 4
        }
    }
 },
```

But when using a "predefined" index

```
<input type="text" name="url[1]" required />
```

the following validation doesn't work

```
'url[]': {
    validators: {
        stringLength: {
             min: 4
        }
    }
 },
```

It works using a fixed index  in the validation code (see below code)

```
'url[1]': {
    validators: {
        stringLength: {
             min: 4
        }
    }
 },
```

However I am dynamically adding fields with an unknown index.
So using a fixed index in the validation code is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer of what you're looking for is on [this](http://formvalidation.io/examples/validating-array-inputs/) page and then the second section "Inputs with different names".

There you can validate on the css class of you're flied

```
 <fieldname>: {
                    //the input css class
                    selector: '<.cssClass>',
                    // The field is placed inside .col-xs-6 div instead of .form-group
                    row: '.col-xs-6',
                    validators: {
                        <your validator>
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

With formvalidation.io version 1.9.0, this is what works for me:

```
<input type="text" name="myvar[1]" />
<input type="text" name="myvar[2]" />
<input type="text" name="myvar[3]" />
```

Use the `selector` option to validate all variable names that start with "myvar["

```
'this_can_be_anything': {
    selector: 'input[name^="myvar["]',
    validators: {
        stringLength: {
             min: 4
        }
    }
 },
```

More details can be found here:
https://formvalidation.io/guide/getting-started/field-selector/